# What does "Who owns this PC?" in the Windows 10 setup mean?

Tags: windows-10

While setting up Windows 10 Pro (clean install), I was presented with a question: "Who owns this PC?" Legally speaking, I own this PC. I don't plan on doing extensive file sharing, but I might consider joining it to the domain I have at home. This is not a WDS installation, though there is a WDS server active on the network, if that makes any difference.

It's apparently not easy to change my decision, so I want to choose the right one for my situation. "My organization" was selected by default, but I think that's because this is the Pro edition. What will my response to the question actually do? That is, what are the specific effects of each choice?

[image: the question in question]

<sup>(this screenshot is from a slightly earlier build, but I'm using the final release)</sup>

Comment: might be related to licensing

Comment: Great question! I assume it allow you to join a domain at installation, but should be able to at a later date if you choose "I do"

Comment: [Choosing "I do" allows you to set up a local account if you want to](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-install-windows-10-without-microsoft-account/)

Comment: Your getting this question because a domain was detected

Comment: You still can join a domain if you choose "I do" !

Comment: And choosing "My organization" also lets you proceed to create a local account and then join a domain later (if you want). Just selected 'Join a domain' in the next screen and then it'll let you enter a local account name etc.

Comment: If anybody's wondering about the weird protection/unprotection in this question's timeline, I was testing stuff for [this MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283949/295684).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ben,

The short answer to your question is, there's no harm in picking the second option if you want to join an Active Directory (AD) domain or Azure later.  Microsoft is trying to help you set up the computer correctly, that's all.

Just remember that if you're using a local account – downloads/documents/etc. in your local account don't usually transfer over to an AD/Azure account.  You can still get to them as long as you are a Computer Admin on your AD/Azure account, but it's a time-consuming process.

Yes, the language is confusing, and no, it doesn't seem Microsoft has an official document for it yet.  Google/Bing searched it, nothing found with an official explanation, just lots of How-To guides that don't really discuss the ramifications of each option.

If you want to add it to AD/Azure immediately or very soon, pick the first option.  Otherwise, pick the second option.

Using Windows 10 Pro with a local account (second option), I have the "Join or leave a domain' and "Join or leave Azure" buttons under Settings -> Accounts -> Work Access.

More info here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74217ce8-6933-4f47-8101-7ad99922125b/who-owns-this-pc-my-work-owns-it-vs-i-own-it-small-home-networrk-with-server-2012-r2-active?forum=win10itprosetup

Answer (score 1):

This question matters if your PC belongs to a domain or if you use a business Office 365 account.

If you have an Office 365 account, say that the company owns the PC. The next step lets you login with your that account. This will automatically set you up with your SharePoint and, hopefully, mitigate the annoyance of having two different Microsoft accounts.

If you choose "I own this PC", then you login with your normal/personal account instead and use that to sync everything up (e.g. with OneDrive).

This decision will choose the correct apps, settings and permissions for your situation.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the lead. Do you know what specific settings and permissions it puts into place? I am also curious as to why it's allegedly so difficult to change the decision.

Comment: @Ben N, that's probably a whole other question (which, if one like it hasn't been posted before, you may want to post as a new questions). It seems to me your question here has been basically answered? If so, please mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: @BenN, It has always been difficult to switch from one user to another without significant data migration.  This is no different; if you build your profile as corpuser(at)mydomain.com and then decide you'd prefer to be personaluser(at)outlook.com, you'll need to migrate everything.  Pretty normal stuff.  With Windows 10 I have stopped using my (at)outlook.com account as my login and now use my (at)o365.com account instead.  So now I see OneDrive for Business as my default - not OneDrive.  My default email is now myname(at)o365.com - no longer is it myname(at)outlook.com.    Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is the option to allow you to join a domain or keep the PC (OS) installation separate of any "Parent." This doesn't mean you cannot join up later, simply that it is a more sophisticated (modern) way of asking you if you want to join a domain or not, or if it is a share.

Answer (score 0):

For an individual you need to select it as `I Do`, the option that is used only for companies who want to keep all machines on same domain / specific server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it belongs to you so "I do" would be your choice if you have it at home, I'm guessing that your job didn't buy it for you? And if they did and you use it at home and your job doesn't want it back, then it's "I do".

If your job wants it back eventually then it's "My organization" I believe, I coul be wrong though so don't quote me on it.

But yeah, that's my theory.

That beeing said, [This might be useful](https://blogs.windows.com/business/2014/09/30/introducing-windows-10-for-business/).

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help. The following is to help you become better at answering, so don't take wrong. It is important to read the question carefully. As you will find the OP stated they own the PC. In addition, your answer doesn't really answer the question, nor does the link you provided. Rather, as you stated, it is your theory. You may want to take a look at [How do I write a good answer](http://superuser.com/help/answering) for tips to improve.